# Как обернуть collection_select элементом dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть такой код на ruby, который внутри тэгов input и select... отображает список c разными значениями для последующего выбора и отправки на сервер:

```
f.collection_select(:outlets, Outlet.order(:name), :id, :name, { include_blank: false, }, { :multiple => true, :class=>'select2'})
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы эти данные выводились не просто внутри input, а внутри элемента dropdown? Мне хочется вывести не в стандартном select, а через bootstrap dropdown w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp Спасибо.